# Javascript - Change Object when Extended Function called

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a code like this:

```
var Vec = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
};

Vec.prototype = {
  set: function(v) {
    this.v.x = v.x;
    this.v.y = v.y;

    return this;
  },

  add: function(add) {
    if (add instanceof Vec) {
      return new Vec(this.v.x + add.x, this.v.y + add.y);
    } else {
      return new Vec(this.v.x + add, this.v.y + add);
    }
  }
};
```

This is how I then create it:

```
var MyVector = new Vector(32, 46);
```

Instead of this doing each time when I want to add to MyVector;

```
MyVector.set(MyVector.add(new Vec(12, 7))); // MyVector = MyVector.add(new Vec(12, 7)); Same thing
```

I want to be able to do like this:

```
MyVector.add(new Vec(12, 7)).set();
```

How do I make that possible?

Comment: How does `set` know which vector you're referring to? `MyVector` is one object, and the return value of `.add` is another object. Without giving more information to `set` or storing information in `MyVector`, you can't decide which object you want to mutate.

Comment: MyVector.set(this.add(new Vec(12, 7))); Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Vec = function(a,b) {
  return {
     x: a,
     y: b,

     set: function(vector) {
       this.x = vector.x;
       this.y = vector.y;
     },

     get: function() {
       return {x: this.x, y:this.y};
     },       

    add: function(v) {
      if(s.constructor === new Vec().constructor) {
        values = v.get();
        this.x += values.x;
        this.y += values.y;
      } 
      else {
        this.x += v;
        this.y += v;
      }

    }
 }
}
```

Now you could just say:

```
 var v = new Vec(12,13);
 v.add(new Vect(14,15));
```

Comment: just a minute, the add is a bit off.

Comment: No, not like that, when you do V1.add(V2) it should return the sum, not set it, it should only set it when you do V1.add(V2).set()